# How would I show if a column in a DataGridView has data with just an X

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with 4 columns. The code I'm using to build its datasource is this:

```
DataTable vTbl = new DataTable();      
using(SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
  {
    string query = "select site, username, password, notes from Passwords order by site, username";
    using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, c))
    {
      c.Open();
      vTbl.Clear();
      da.Fill(vTbl);
      c.Close();
    }
  }

  dataGridView1.DataSource = vTbl;
```

Now the fourth column which contains notes is a data type of nvarchar(max) in the table. So what I'd like to do is just show a mark (like an X) if this field is not empty or nulled and show nothing if the field IS empty or nulled.

I'm thinking there is something to do with the query variable, but I just can't place it.

Can someone please help me out?

Thanks,

Bob Gatto

Comment: TBH, adjust your query for this, you're binding to that data that's coming from `sql`... It doesn't make sense to return data and then handle it again when you can *get the format you need* already.

Answer (score -1):

Here is simple way using linq :

```
            vTbl.Columns.Add("X", typeof(string));

            foreach(DataRow row in vTbl.AsEnumerable())
            {
                if (row.Field<string>(3).Length > 0)
                {
                    row[4] = "X";
                }
            }
            vTbl.Columns.Remove("Column Name");
```